# JNLP Native Library jawt.dl already loaded in another classloader

Tags: java, dll, classloader, java-web-start, jnlp

I Have the Following Error when I try to Run an JNLP File, that I downloaded from a Website.  I Just want to Know if the Problem Lies with my Computer or the File Itself. If its in my Computer, then Please provide the Steps to Rectify it. If the Question here should have been Posted in Other sites other than Stackoverflow, then mention the other Site

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="https://www.org"
      href="https://www.org/download-jnlp.php?">
    <information>
        <title>xxx</title>
        <vendor>JS</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://www.org/" />
        <description>xxx</description>
        <icon href="/sts1-minicut.jpg"/> 
        <shortcut online="false">
            <desktop/>
            <menu submenu="xxx.org"/>
        </shortcut>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <update check="always" policy="always" />
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.8.0*" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" java-vm-args="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote" initial-heap-size="500M" />
        <j2se version="9+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" java-vm-args="--add-modules=java.xml.ws" initial-heap-size="500M" />
        <jar href="Loader.jar" download="progress"/>
        <jar href="sts.jar" main="true" download="eager"/>
        <jar href="js-tools.jar" download="eager"/>
        <jar href="STSQuery.jar" download="eager"/>
        <jar href="flatlaf.jar" download="eager"/>
<!--        <jar href="flatlaf-themes.jar" download="eager"/> -->

        <property name="jnlp.ircserver" value="bespin.org"/>
        <property name="jnlp.timeserver" value="bespin.org"/>
        <property name="jnlp.webserver" value="www.org"/>
        <property name="jnlp.service" value="https://www.org/soap.php"/>
        <property name="jnlp.log" value="www.org/javalog.php"/>
        <property name="jnlp.controlbot" value="sts-control"/>
        <property name="jnlp.controlroomPrefix" value="#control"/>
        <property name="jnlp.readyroom" value="#readyroom"/>
        <property name="jnlp.readyroomchannels" value="#Lobby:Lobby;#quassel:Spielanfragen"/>
        <property name="jnlp.mixfilterchannels" value="#Lobby"/>
        <property name="jnlp.startchannel" value="#lobby"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc
        name="xxx"
        main-class="js.java.schaltungen.stsmain"
        width="300"
        height="300">
        <argument>006195686ce449</argument>
        <argument>58441</argument>
        <argument>matmut</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Problem is in app, not you machine. It is impossible to tell more without seeing source code of application.

Comment: I have Updates the Code without the Original Website Links, but the Code is the Same